# Can't scroll to elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

I'm trying to create a scroll animation when a button is clicked. However when the button is clicked, nothing happens and I don't see any errors in chrome dev tools.

This is how I try to use the scrolling effect

```
$('.js--scroll-to-plan').click(function() 
 {

    $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top
        }, 1000
    )
})
```

I also tried the following

```
$(document).on('click','.js--scroll-to-plan',function() 
 {

    $('html, body').animate(
        {
            scrollTop: $('.js--section-plans').offset().top
        }, 1000
    )
})
```

But nothing seems to work.

Also I set the `overflow` to be hidden in the body selector.

**Edit:** I tested it on IE and it works there. It doesn't work on Firefox and it doesn't work on Chrome

Comment: Does `$('.js--section-plans').offset().top` actually return a number?

Comment: Do you have multiple `.js--section-plans` class elements in the code or just one?

Comment: @Terry how do I know if it returns a number?

Comment: @palaѕн I have only one element with that class

Comment: console log it or use debugger. Open your browse dev tools.

Comment: Add your html too

Comment: I tested it on other browsers IE, Chrome and Firefox and the scrolling works only in IE.

Comment: I found the problem. I had overflow-x:hidden both in html and body selectors. Once I removed it from HTML and left only in the body the scrolling started to work in Chrome and Firefox